# Calculate the distances between points of different colours in FIJI/ImageJ

Tags: image-processing, macros, fiji

I'm trying to calculate the distances between points of different colours, as shown in this image:

[image: dots]

The goal is to use a macro to print the distances from the red dot to the yellow dot and then the yellow dot to the purple dot. I believe the best way to do this is to either:

1) Use a macro to print the coordinates of the red dots, and then a macro to print the coordinates of the closest yellow dots. Then a second macro to print the coordinates of the purple dots closest to a given yellow dot. I would also like to calculate the angle of the line relative to the center point, but I believe I can do this in Excel if I'm given the XY coordinates of each point as well.

2) Drawing lines between the red and yellow points and the yellow and purple points, printing the length and angle of those lines.

Ideally being able to do both would be good, but either would work for my purposes (calculating the distance and angle of the lines between the points from red to yellow and yellow to purple).

What is the best way to do this via macro? There are some examples (like [this](https://forum.image.sc/t/perpendicular-distance-between-2-lines-shortest-distance-between-2-lines/3862/5?u=herbie)) but I don't believe it 1) selects for points based on colour or 2) picks the next closest point automatically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code and specify where exactly you are having problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Threshold Color function, I should think it would allow you to select your colors individually.  You can then get the coordinates for your different points by selecting "centroid" from the Analyze menu.  The calculations for the angles and distances can be done then in Excel if you use the closest coordinates for the relevant colors.